# Debug Start from Notification after Store Installation

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, desktop-bridge

I have an app up and running on the Microsoft Store. It is a Desktop App using the Desktop Bridge. The app launches and runs whitout any problems also when installing from the Store. However, after installing the app from the store, the users gets, like for any other app, a System notification if he wants to start the App. When trying to launch my app this way it crashes. The eventviewer shows the log below. Is there a way to debug this app launch? What does happen when the users presses "start" after app installation?

```
    EventData 

   svchost.exe_WpnUserService 
   10.0.17763.1 
   b900eeff 
   NotificationController.dll 
   10.0.17763.292 
   aba6e357 
   c0000005 
   00000000000de666 
   3b24 
   01d4d846e66e9389 
   C:\Windows\system32\svchost.exe 
   C:\Windows\System32\NotificationController.dll 
   881f9f93-ec25-44bd-9b70-21ed4d1dd427
```

Comment: What if your user just click the lanuch your app from start menu, will they see the same exception? I'm not aware of such a way to debug this notification process.

Comment: The app launches without problems from the Starmenu

Comment: Does this happen when you install other app from the Store? Do you encounter this issue when you install this Desktop bridge app on other devices?

Comment: It does not happen with other apps from the store.  I tested it on other devices with the same result.